# Total of multiple computed elements

Tags: webforms

I am trying to create a quote form where I can add two computed twig elements together to give a total of the two. I have created the two computed elements to give a total based on the user inputs but when I then create the third computed element it doesn't add the two together. It just gives me a value of two. Below is the export of the Webform. What am I doing wrong please or am I going about this wrong? Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated :)

Drupal version 8.9.13 - Webform Version: 6.0.2

[image: front end quote form]
[image: Webform form build]

```
uuid: b6d7a837-6396-4fe5-af62-9a15bbf50cb2
langcode: en
status: open
dependencies: {  }
open: null
close: null
weight: 0
uid: 1
template: false
archive: false
id: quote_builder
title: 'Quote builder'
description: ''
category: ''
elements: |
  how_many_sockets_:
    '#type': textfield
    '#title': 'How many sockets?'
  cost_per_socket:
    '#type': hidden
    '#title': 'Cost per socket'
    '#default_value': '45'
    '#prepopulate': true
  total_cost_of_sockets:
    '#type': webform_computed_twig
    '#title': 'Total cost of sockets'
    '#display_on': view
    '#template': '{{( data.how_many_sockets_ * data.cost_per_socket )}}'
    '#store': true
  how_many_light_fittings_including_down_lights_:
    '#type': textfield
    '#title': 'How many light fittings? (including down lights)'
  cost_per_light_fitting:
    '#type': hidden
    '#title': 'cost per light fitting'
    '#default_value': '35'
    '#prepopulate': true
  total_cost_of_light_fittings:
    '#type': webform_computed_twig
    '#title': 'total cost of light fittings'
    '#display_on': view
    '#template': '{{( data.how_many_light_fittings_including_down_lights_ * data.cost_per_light_fitting )}}'
    '#store': true
  total_cost_of_sockets_and_light_fittings:
    '#type': webform_computed_twig
    '#title': 'Total cost of sockets and light fittings'
    '#template': '{{( data.total_cost_of_sockets + data.total_cost_of_light_fittings )}}'
    '#store': true
    '#ajax': true
css: ''
javascript: ''
settings:
  ajax: false
  ajax_scroll_top: form
  ajax_progress_type: ''
  ajax_effect: ''
  ajax_speed: null
  page: true
  page_submit_path: ''
  page_confirm_path: ''
  page_theme_name: ''
  form_title: both
  form_submit_once: false
  form_exception_message: ''
  form_open_message: ''
  form_close_message: ''
  form_previous_submissions: true
  form_confidential: false
  form_confidential_message: ''
  form_disable_remote_addr: false
  form_convert_anonymous: false
  form_prepopulate: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity_required: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity_type: ''
  form_reset: false
  form_disable_autocomplete: false
  form_novalidate: false
  form_disable_inline_errors: false
  form_required: false
  form_unsaved: false
  form_disable_back: false
  form_submit_back: false
  form_autofocus: false
  form_details_toggle: false
  form_access_denied: default
  form_access_denied_title: ''
  form_access_denied_message: ''
  form_access_denied_attributes: {  }
  form_file_limit: ''
  share: false
  share_node: false
  share_theme_name: ''
  share_title: true
  share_page_body_attributes: {  }
  submission_label: ''
  submission_log: false
  submission_views: {  }
  submission_views_replace: {  }
  submission_user_columns: {  }
  submission_user_duplicate: false
  submission_access_denied: default
  submission_access_denied_title: ''
  submission_access_denied_message: ''
  submission_access_denied_attributes: {  }
  submission_exception_message: ''
  submission_locked_message: ''
  submission_excluded_elements: {  }
  submission_exclude_empty: false
  submission_exclude_empty_checkbox: false
  previous_submission_message: ''
  previous_submissions_message: ''
  autofill: false
  autofill_message: ''
  autofill_excluded_elements: {  }
  wizard_progress_bar: true
  wizard_progress_pages: false
  wizard_progress_percentage: false
  wizard_progress_link: false
  wizard_progress_states: false
  wizard_auto_forward: true
  wizard_auto_forward_hide_next_button: false
  wizard_keyboard: true
  wizard_start_label: ''
  wizard_preview_link: false
  wizard_confirmation: true
  wizard_confirmation_label: ''
  wizard_track: ''
  wizard_prev_button_label: ''
  wizard_next_button_label: ''
  wizard_toggle: false
  wizard_toggle_show_label: ''
  wizard_toggle_hide_label: ''
  preview: 0
  preview_label: ''
  preview_title: ''
  preview_message: ''
  preview_attributes: {  }
  preview_excluded_elements: {  }
  preview_exclude_empty: true
  preview_exclude_empty_checkbox: false
  draft: none
  draft_multiple: false
  draft_auto_save: false
  draft_saved_message: ''
  draft_loaded_message: ''
  draft_pending_single_message: ''
  draft_pending_multiple_message: ''
  confirmation_type: page
  confirmation_title: ''
  confirmation_message: ''
  confirmation_url: ''
  confirmation_attributes: {  }
  confirmation_back: true
  confirmation_back_label: ''
  confirmation_back_attributes: {  }
  confirmation_exclude_query: false
  confirmation_exclude_token: false
  confirmation_update: false
  limit_total: null
  limit_total_interval: null
  limit_total_message: ''
  limit_total_unique: false
  limit_user: null
  limit_user_interval: null
  limit_user_message: ''
  limit_user_unique: false
  entity_limit_total: null
  entity_limit_total_interval: null
  entity_limit_user: null
  entity_limit_user_interval: null
  purge: none
  purge_days: null
  results_disabled: false
  results_disabled_ignore: false
  results_customize: false
  token_view: false
  token_update: false
  token_delete: false
  serial_disabled: false
access:
  create:
    roles:
      - anonymous
      - authenticated
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  view_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  update_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  delete_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  purge_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  view_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  update_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  delete_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  administer:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  test:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  configuration:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
handlers: {  }
variants: {  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, computations cannot draw values from other computed elements. You always have to go back to the original elements.

Here is the working Twig code for the “Total cost of sockets and light fittings“ element:

```
{{
  data.how_many_sockets_ * data.cost_per_socket + 
  data.how_many_light_fittings_including_down_lights_ * data.cost_per_light_fitting
}}
```